# How can ı get just specific variables in spring?

Tags: rest, api, spring-mvc, post

For example, when I want to get properties of them but not all of them. For example, when I use findAll(); function - it displays everything but I wanna for example just `id` and `name` there is any special function or anything for doing this?

Think that ı have an entity class like that.

```
     @Id
     private int api_id;

     @Column(name = "id")
     private int id;

     @Column(name = "name")
     private String name;

     @Column(name = "city")
     private String city;

     @Column(name = "founded_at")
     private int founded_at; //I declare as a integer because the variable consists of 4 integers.

     @Column(name = "web_page")
     private String web_page;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `spring-data`'s interface based projections to select particular fields from DB:

```
interface NameAndIdOnly {
    int getId();
    String getName();
}
```

and in your repository:

```
...
List<NameAndIdOnly> findAllWithNameAndId();
...
```

This will do `select id, name from <table>`.

Please read [Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) for more info.